# How to get mouse position in float or double with exact resolution?

Tags: java, coordinates, mouseevent, point

I need to take the mouse click position in float or double, how can I do that?In mouse listener, I take the point like this,

```
e.getPoint();
```

but Point object's x and y values are integer, I need position in float or double.
Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**
**I need exact resolution.**

Comment: You can cast an `int` to a `float` or a `double` as you wish. No problem here. Or do you want sub-pixel resolution for the cursor position? I don't think you can get that.

Comment: I need exact resolution.

Comment: The **exact** resolution is the integer value returned. The screen coordinate system is integer based, so there is no more "resolution" to be had through the usage of floating point numbers.

Comment: There is something wrong with your question.
Cursor coordinates are in int, because the screen contains a precise number of pixels (which depends upon your screen resolution, but I fear this is off-topic). As a consequence, your cursor coordinates will always be returned as int.

What I think is that you want to map mouse position to an object which have a float or double position (from your comment to danben). Unfortunatly, for finding that object, you'll have to find the nearest to mouse, since mouse will always have an int position, which **is** its exact one.

Comment: @EEE: what do you mean, "exact resolution"? Do you mean more precise than the pixel grid? I don't know if this is possible, but perhaps you could look into trying to get raw access to the mouse device.

Comment: @mctylr,By saying "The exact resolution is the integer value returned.", I suppose you mean I cannot reach floating point coordinate, but you are wrong. I can successfully draw in, for example 255,5 .

Comment: @EEE: you can draw there, but you can't know if the mouse is positioned at that point (at least not in pure Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPoint()` gives you integer values because that is the precision in which coordinates are specified.  See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html.

Why do you need floating-point values?

**Edit**: in response to your comment, you will need to map your absolute positions to onscreen pixels, using a function like floor (always round down) or round (round to nearest int).  The system has no notion of 0.2 pixels or anything like that.  You can either continually truncate the decimal part of your calculations, or maintain the exact coordinates at all times and map them to pixels as needed.

Comment: I have an animation with some objects, whose speeds, accelerations are  not fixed, and I move those objects in the panel according to the displacement they have. Objects sometimes needs to move, lets say 100,2 in x coordinate, and I need this exact position.

Comment: @EEE: and how exactly is the user supposed to move the mouse with sub-pixel precision? First of all he gets no feedback that tells him if he's at 10.1 or 10.2 and then there's the tiny problem that most people can't do that kind of precision-movement anyway. It's meaningless to have that value in a precision that's higher than the users actual capability of precision.

Answer (score 1):

From `int` you should be able to cast to `double` or `float` without any problems:

```
double x = e.getPoint().x;
double y = e.getPoint().y;
```

There are however methods that already do that:

```
double x = e.getPoint().getX();
double y = e.getPoint().getY();
```

Am I missing something here?

Please note, that the precision will not be higher - the mouse can only snap to full pixels, hence usually integer is fine. But if you need to calculate based on these values, the floating point representations might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need exact resolution. Please see my comment to danben 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a more precise point then `getPoint()`, wich returns a Point object that only holds two integers.
What would like to achieve with this?