# Precise Mouse coordinates in processing

Tags: mouse, processing, precision, decimal

I am tracking mouse coordinates in processing over a jpg image and I was wondering if there is any way to increase the number of decimal points that the x and y coordinates are returning. The image is 1000 pixels by 1000 pixels so I have set the size of the window as that but I would like to get the mouse coordinates to at least 2 decimal places. Is this possible or will it only tracks pixels in the defined space?

Thanks, as always, for the help

Comment: Where would this precision come from? Pixels are only so small, and there are no sub pixels, also, possible duplicate of [How to get mouse position in float or double with exact resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417425/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-float-or-double-with-exact-resolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done; Processing reports the mouse coordinates based on which pixel in the pixel array your cursor is over. Those values are integers.